# Connect Symfony 2 application to SQL SERVER using windows account

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony

I'm trying to connect my symfony 2 application to an SQL SERVER database, everything works fine using SQL SERVER internal account but i need to avoid this by connecting my application throught a Windows account (for example using the windows user that runs the apache service on the web serveur).

Any idea ?

I tried to comment the user/password parameter

## This file is auto-generated during the composer install

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_sqlsrv
#    database_host: xxxxx
    database_host: x.x.x.x
    database_port: 1557
    database_name: xxxxxx
#    database_user: xxxxx
#    database_password: "xxxxx"
```

But i got this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 
'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException'
enter code here
 with message 'You have requested a non-existent parameter "database_user". 
Did you mean one of these: "database_driver", "database_host", 
"database_port", "database_name"?' in ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : Just leave database_user and database_password to null :

```
database_user: null 
database_password: null
```